# Como criar aplicativo sobre programação de eventos?

Tags: android, app

Olá, pessoal!

Estou iniciando minhas atividades como desenvolvedor Android, e como primeiro projeto pensei em criar um aplicativo que pudesse informar ao usuário a programação de atividades fornecidas pela prefeitura, como locais e horários de prática de esportes, shows gratuitos, atividades físicas, feiras de artes e etc. Porém, como sou totalmente principiante, queria que vocês me dessem um norte.

Todos esses dados encontram-se no site da prefeitura, mas não saberia por exemplo como colocá-los no aplicativo.

Seria por meio de banco de dados? O que eu teria que saber para criar um aplicativo como esse?

Comment: Olá Renan. Bem vindo ao SOPT. Por favor, leia [ask]. A sua pergunta está simplesmente ampla demais para este site, que não é um fórum.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Renan!

Seja bem vindo ao mundo Android! Parabéns pela sua iniciativa. Não qual o seu nível de conhecimento para responder uma pergunta tão abrangente, então peço desculpas se explicar coisas que você já sabe ou deixar de explicar algo que você precise.

Para fazer um aplicativo Android você usaria a IDE Android Studio, linguagem Java, Programação Orientada a Objetos (paradigma), linguagem XML e o banco de dados SQLite. Se já conhece o básico dessas tecnologias, eu  recomendaria você a acompanhar um curso básico de Android no youtube, existem alguns muito bons, para pode entender melhor como cada uma dessas tecnologias são usadas dentro de um aplicativo.

Para esse aplicativo que você presente fazer, você usaria um web service, que será um segundo projeto além do aplicativo. Nesse caso, você teria que usar uma linguagem para sistemas web. Recomendo usar o Java, que também serve para a web além do Android, para que inclusive mantenha a prática do que tem usado no aplicativo Android.

O aplicativo Android pedirá os dados ao web service que iria até onde estão os dados dos eventos e os coletaria. Depois de coletado, o web service retorna os dados aplicação.

A aplicação pede os dados de eventos ao web service:
Aplicação -> pede dados-> Web service -> busca-> Dados

Depois de coletar os dados: 
Web service -> envia dados -> aplicação.

Espero que tenha conseguido mostrar como ficaria a estrutura para você de forma resumida. Você vai precisar de uma aplicação e um web service, sendo que na aplicação você vai usar Android Studio, Java, Programação Orientada a Objeto, XMl e SQLite. Segue um [vídeo inicial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cnv905AFs8o)!

Abraços!